# Selenium Secure Socket Layer Issue in Selenium 3

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How could I handle ssl certifiaction error in selenium 3 and above for firefox 49+.

It will be helpful if anyone could answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflow's content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: For Firefox use FirefoxProfile and for chrome use DesiredCapabilities  class to set Selenium Secure Socket Layer Issue in Selenium 3

Answer (score 0):

For chrome :

```
DesiredCapabilities SSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
SSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (lSSLErr);
```

or

```
ChromeOptions option= new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("headless");
option.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver(option);
```

For Firefox

```
FirefoxProfile profileSSL = new FirefoxProfile();
profileSSL.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true); 
profileSSL.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profileSSL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Actually none of the above worked for me, I am using Selenium 2.35.1 and Firefox 49. So I used try catch method, where I am catching that WebDriverException and clicking on exception using selenium and AutoIT to close the window based popup